# C Program makefile in linux

Tags: c, makefile

I'm a beginner. I'd like to create a makefile for C programs in Linux.

My program flow is,
`cmd.c` calls `cdirec(), dspecd(), sfile(), hfile()` which are declared in `mainl.h` (but not defined in it)

`cdirec(), dspecd(), sfile() and hfile()` are defined in `cdirec.c, dspecd.c, sfile.c` and `hfile.c` respectively.

`cdirec()` in turn calls `mimx(), skloc(), fnc() and fcmp()` which are declared in `subl.h` (but not defined in it)

`mimx(), skloc(), fnc() and fcmp()` are defined in `mimx.c, skloc.c, fnc.c and fcmp.c` respectively.

I tried to create a makefile as follows,

```
all: cmd.o cdir.o dspecd.o sfile.o hfile.o
    cc cmd.o cdir.o dspecd.o sfile.o hfile.o -o sourceinfo
cmd.o: cmd.c mainl.h
    cc -c cmd.c
cdir.o: cdirec.o mimx.o skloc.o fnc.o fcmp.o
    cc cdirec.o mimx.o skloc.o fnc.o fcmp.o -o cdir.o
cdirec.o: cdirec.c mainl.h subl.h
    cc -c cdirec.c
dspecd.o: dspecd.c mainl.h
    cc -c dspecd.c
sfile.o: sfile.c mainl.h
    cc -c sfile.c
hfile.o: hfile.c mainl.h
    cc -c hfile.c
mimx.o: mimx.c subl.h
    cc -c mimx.c
skloc.o: skloc.c subl.h
    cc -c skloc.c
fnc.o: fnc.c subl.h
    cc -c fnc.c
fcmp.o: fcmp.c subl.h
    cc -c fcmp.c
```

I don't understand what the problem is. But I get an undefined reference to main in `cdir.o`. cdirec.c looks like this,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "subl.h"

void cdirec()
{
printf("\nAll details of current directory is printed.\n");
mimx();
skloc();
fnc();
fcmp();
}
```

I don't and can't have a main in it, as it is just a function declaration file.
Kindly guide me.

ANSWER:

```
all: cmd.o cdirec.o dspecd.o sfile.o hfile.o mimx.o skloc.o fnc.o fcmp.o 
    cc cmd.o cdirec.o dspecd.o sfile.o hfile.o mimx.o skloc.o fnc.o fcmp.o -o sourceinfo
cmd.o: cmd.c mainl.h
    cc -c cmd.c
cdirec.o: cdirec.c mainl.h subl.h
    cc -c cdirec.c
dspecd.o: dspecd.c mainl.h
    cc -c dspecd.c
sfile.o: sfile.c mainl.h
    cc -c sfile.c
hfile.o: hfile.c mainl.h
    cc -c hfile.c
mimx.o: mimx.c subl.h
    cc -c mimx.c
skloc.o: skloc.c subl.h
    cc -c skloc.c
fnc.o: fnc.c subl.h
    cc -c fnc.c
fcmp.o: fcmp.c subl.h
    cc -c fcmp.c
clean:
    rm -rf *.o sourceinfo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs here:

```
cdir.o: cdirec.o mimx.o skloc.o fnc.o fcmp.o
    cc cdirec.o mimx.o skloc.o fnc.o fcmp.o -o cdir.o
```

This is telling `cc` to link these given `.o` files into an executable named `cdir.o`. An executable needs a `main` function. But it looks like you're not trying to link an executable; instead, you're trying to collect multiple object files into a single object file.

You don't need to do this; you can just link all of your object files together in the final executable. If you just find it cumbersome to deal with that many files on one line, you can define a Make variable; a common name is `OBJS` (short for "objects"):

```
OBJS  = cdirec.o 
OBJS += mimx.o 
OBJS += skloc.o 
OBJS += fnc.o 
OBJS += fcmp.o 
# ... etc

sourceinfo: ${OBJS}
    cc ${OBJS} -o sourceinfo
```

If you want to collect them into a single file, you can build a library, and then link that into the final executable. A library is built with the `ar` command; it should have the extension `.a`:

```
cdir.a: cdirec.o mimx.o skloc.o fnc.o fcmp.o
    ar rcs cdir.a cdirec.o mimx.o skloc.o fnc.o fcmp.o
```

You then link that when building your final executable:

```
cc cmd.o dspecd.o sfile.o hfile.o cdir.a -o sourceinfo
```

As an aside on your organization, it looks like you might be defining one function per source file. That gets pretty cumbersome pretty quick. You usually group related functions together in the same source file. It's possible that all of `cdirec()`, `mimx()` `skloc()`, `fnc()` and `fcmp()` should be defined in the same file, so that they produce a single object file, though I can't say for sure without seeing your actual code.

There are also further features in Make that would make your Makefile much simpler. In particular, there are already implicit rules for compiling `.c` files into `.o`, so you don't need all those rules, just the dependencies on the headers (because those aren't generated implicitly):

```
cmd.o: mainl.h
cdirec.o: mainl.h subl.h
dspecd.o: mainl.h
sfile.o: mainl.h
hfile.o: mainl.h
mimx.o: subl.h
skloc.o: subl.h
fnc.o: subl.h
fcmp.o: subl.h
```

You can actually generate these dependencies automatically as well, but that's a [bit more complicated](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html), so I won't go into it here.

Comment: Put the `-lcdir` after the object files, or it will be ignored (only the parts unresolved till now will be taken, i.e. none.)

Comment: @glglgl Ah, right. I forget that's true of GNU `ld`, because it's not true of `ld` on Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks. Where in the program should I use this line 'ar'?

Comment: @Gomathi That's a replacement for the `cc cdirec.o ... -o cdir.o` line. And it produces a file name `libcdir.a`, so the dependencies should read `libcdir.a: cdirec.o ...`, then the line I gave you. I'll clarify in my answer.

Comment: Now, am getting an error as, `cmd.o: In function 'main': cmd.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to cdirec'`. What to do, now?

Comment: @Gomathi I realize that I was over-complicating the use of the library; you only need the `lib` prefix and `-L. -l` options if you want to search; instead of all of that, you can just pass the library in to be linked when linking the executable. I've simplified my answer.

Comment: @Gomathi I can't really tell without seeing the final Makefile you used. Can you update your question to include the whole thing? I'd also recommend trying to test it out building a project with just two or three source files; once you get it working for a small test project, expand it to your full project. That will make it easier to debug, and easier to ask questions about without listing the full contents of every file.

Comment: Thank you so much for spending time, Mam. Instead of using archive, I just tried for linking them all together. It works now, Mam. I have updated it. Is this method correct?

Comment: @Gomathi Yes, it's correct. It's a little verbose; you could make it shorter by taking advantage of some of my other tips (using a variable to avoid repeating the list of objects; using implicit rules), but it certainly looks correct. By the way, "Mam" isn't quite the correct form of address, though I can see how you might be confused by the long hair and pink cupcake on my head.

Comment: Sorry for that usage of 'mam'. Also, I will shorten it with the help of your tips. Thanks, again.

Comment: Could you please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950379/finding-the-function-complexity-index) question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not trying to create a static/dynamic library, you need to have main somewhere. Add some test file with main, and compile with that file. 
Also I don't think any need for all those *.o to be mentioned explicitly. The Make is smart enough to figure that out.

Answer (score -1):

Do not bother with hand writing of dependencies. Use `autotools` or light version -- `gcc -MM ./*`.