# Finding the function complexity index

Tags: c, performance, complexity-theory

I have to find the complexity of a C file based on the number of lines. I have found the number of lines. But how to decide whether it is a complex file or not? Based on certain value, I have to give it an index. For eg., complexity index - 5 for high complexity. On which basis can I index it? More than 1000 lines for high complex, for eg., won't apply for all. Is there any standard way for giving conditions('more than 1000 lines')? Any kind of suggestions are welcome, except any pre-defined tools. I need to program it in C. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

Comment: You can't define the complexity of certain code based just in the number of lines due complexity refers to the computer effort to execute the program, not to the human effort writing the code.

Comment: @adripanico Yes. I know it is a bad way of finding the complexity. But, any ways taking into account that I have to implement it (no. of lines), can you suggest any threshold, based on which I can index it? Thanks.

Comment: you could count lines, loops and ifs and make a heuristic with that.

Comment: [here](http://www.whiteboxtest.com/Tools-CodeComplexity.php) you have some tools to calc it. I guess you could use it in your program

Comment: @duedl0r Yes, but if I should do it, I need some threshold value based on which I can decide its index. For eg., More than 20 loops, has complexity 1. More than 30 loops, has complexity 2. How do I set this condition generically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comlexity is not based on lines, for example:

`while(n!=0) {a+=b;n--;}`

the complex is n
and another exapmle:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {for(j=0;j<n;j++) {a+=b} }
```

the complexity is n^2

Comment: Thanks. But I want it the other way. Like, if the program has more than 500 lines, it's complexity index is 3 (medium complex program). Can you suggest any specific calculation for the condition, instead of specifying it directly as 'more than 500 lines'?

Comment: is your program is splitted as in: func.s, main.c, header.h?
or is it in one file: good.c (karma you know ;) )

Comment: ok, so i would suggest that the main would be index 0 in complexity, and every 5-10 function it would add +1 to the scale, so you won't be needed to sum the lines because tell you the truth, it doesn't seem right, hope i helped a bit :)

Comment: So, based on the number of functions, we are deciding the complexity. Am I right?

Comment: But, what about recursive function calls, Sir?

Comment: in the method of n, you can count it by space complexity and time complexity, why not in "our" method? every recursive method adds a value to the scale of space coplexity

Comment: But, some times the number of recursive calls may be based on a dynamic value. How to increment the count in that case?

Comment: sorry it took me time to answer, in recursive department, evey function is +1 to the index because instead of lines you will count how many times it runs